# From Coffeescript to ES6 using Rails webpacker, how to manage classes?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, coffeescript

I'm not a well skilled javascript expert.
I'm migrating a very old app to webpacker.
I have a lot of coffeescript files like this:

```
class @SectionTable
  constructor: ->
    @table  = $('#site_section')
    @_dnd()

  _dnd: ->
    @table.tableDnD onDrop: (table, row) ->
      data = $.tableDnD.serialize()
      $.ajax
        type: 'POST'
        url: '/admin/sections/reorder'
        data: data

$ -> new SectionTable()
```

I already created a structure for my Javascript files in webpacker.

I have some page specific scripts and some global script that I init using a init.js file like this

```
import timePicker from './timePicker.js';
import Redactor from './redactor.js';

(function init() {
  const dtPicker = timePicker();
  const redactor = Redactor();
  document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
    dtPicker.init();
    redactor.init();
  });
}());
```

And then, inside timePicker.js, I init single components

```
import 'bootstrap-datetime-picker/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js';
import 'bootstrap-datetime-picker/js/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.it.js';

const timePicker = () => {
    const initDateTimePicker = () => {
      const dateTime = $('.datetime');
      if (dateTime.length > 0) {
        $('.datetime').datetimepicker({
           todayHighlight: true,
           autoclose: true,
           pickerPosition: 'bottom-left',
           todayBtn: true,
           format: 'hh:ii dd/mm/yyyy'
         });
      }
    };
    const init = () => {
      initDateTimePicker();
   };
   return {
     init,
   };
};

export default timePicker;
```

I cannot find a way to adjust my coffeescript objects inside the new logic.
The coffeescript above is very simple, but I have also some complex objects like this:

@Cover = {}

```
class Cover.Preview
  constructor: ->
    @elements    = {} # preview elements, for each tab/preview box
    @element     = $('#cover_format')
    @container   = $('#cover_preview')
    @button      = $('#change_format')
    @url         = @element.data('url')
    @setFormat()
    @bindChange()

  addElement: (element, position) ->
    position = element.position
    @elements[position] = element

  bindChange: ->
    @button.click (event) =>
      event.preventDefault()
      @setFormat()
      $.ajax
        url:      "#{@url}?format=#{@format}"
        dataType: 'html'
        success: (html) =>
          @container.html html
          @rebindDrag()
          @repopulate()

  setFormat: -> @format = @element.val()

  rebindDrag: ->
    Cover.FormElement.init()
    Cover.Preview.Tile.init()

  repopulate: ->
    for position, tile of Cover.Preview.Tile.all
      tile.redraw Cover.preview.elements[position]



$ ->
  Cover.preview = new Cover.Preview()
```

I understand that I have a couple of ways to to this:

1) keep coffeescript and add coffeescript files loader inside webpacker, but I cannot understand how to Init my coffee defined objects inside the init file (and not in the coffee file like now)

2) convert from coffee to ES6, I try with the online tool and I have this result

```
this.SectionTable = class SectionTable {
  constructor() {
    this.table  = $('#dday_section');
    this._dnd();
  }

  _dnd() {
    return this.table.tableDnD({onDrop(table, row) {
      const data = $.tableDnD.serialize();
      return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/admin/sections/reorder',
        data
      });
    }
    });
  }
};

$(() => new SectionTable());
```

How can I add a modular approach? So basically I want to create the new `SectionTable` in my init file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an example:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

export class SectionTable {
  constructor() {
   this.table = $('#site_section');
   this._dnd();
}
  _dnd() {
   this.table.tableDnD.onDrop((table, row) => {
      const data = $.tableDnD.serialize();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/admin/sections/reorder',
        data: data
      });
   });
  }
}
// if you need a single instance like seems to from your code
export default new SectionTable();
```

```
// otherfile.js
// this is just to show you how you can import only some classes from a file when
// export is used
import SectionTableSingleTon, { SectionTable } from './somewhere/SectionTable';

const sectionTable = new SectionTable();
```

just be cafeful with 'this' with object methods. If you need to pass it around bind it in the constructor.

```
constructor() {
   this.someMethod = this.someMethod.bind(this);

}
attachListener(){
   $('button').click(this.someMethod);
}
somemethod(){
// correct this
}
```

And you don't need iife anymore inside an esm module